# Increase number in txt file via php not working

Tags: php

I have this PHP script:

```
file_put_contents($_GET["username"].".txt", $counter);
$counter = file_get_contents(strtolower($_GET["username"]).".txt") + 1;
```

This should increase the content of the text file by 1. But it doesn't edit the text file.

Why's that.

Comment: So, you write the old value to the text file, then read it back and add 1, and wonder why the text file has the old value in it?

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is almost ok, if you just change the lines order, but I would recommend something like this :

```
$old = file_get_contents(strtolower($_GET["username"]).".txt");
if( !$old )
{
    $old = 0;
}
$new = $old + 1;
file_put_contents($_GET["username"].".txt", $new);
```

security point :
Never pass user input directly into functions such as file_get_contents, use a validation and escape certain characters and preferably use a whitelist

for example, to allow only letters and numbers :

```
if( !ctype_alnum( $_GET['username'] ) )
{
   die( 'invalid ...' );
}
```

Comment: is there a way I can only allow letters and numbers?

Comment: The security fix makes everything go blank.

Comment: sorry I missed a ), try again

Comment: If you're going to use `strtolower` on the username, make sure you use it in both references. As it stands, if I put a user name of Greg, it will read from greg.txt but write to Greg.txt, which is an important difference unless you're on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write to the file after increasing the counter. So first get the value then write it.

```
$counter = file_get_contents(strtolower($_GET["username"]).".txt") + 1;
file_put_contents($_GET["username"].".txt", $counter);
```